# Installing MySQL Connector Net 5.2.7 to Windows Server 2008 (64bit)

Tags: windows, mysql

I installed an MSI package of the MySQL Connector/Net 5.2.7 which I acquired from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.2.html) for 2008 Windows Server Standard 64bit (SP1).

The following issues occured:

1. I asked the program to be installed for "All Users"
2. The Start Menu items only display for "User A", when it needs to display for "User B" as well
3. I was able to run the item from User B by starting it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to hope that I got this answer correct, because your initial question was poorly translated (but hey, at least you tried). I've tried to clean it up. If the following is completely wrong, please let me know.

To get the item displaying for all users, you will need to:

1. Right-click on your Start button and choose "Open".
2. Double-click the "Programs" icon
3. Right-click on the MySQL connector folder and choose "Cut"
4. Right-click on the Start button and choose "Open All Users"
5. Right-click on "Programs" and choose "Paste"

The item should now be available for all users on the system. If this is not what you were after, please let us know.